# how to match a group of word and hypen characters with a separator that can occur zero or n times?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

My regex to match the below pattern doesn't work . Please can you let me know where I am going wrong?

I can have groups of word characters and hyphen separated by zero to four dots

```
[\w-]*(\.\w*)?\.\w*\.\w*\.\w*
```

SOME EXAMPLES ARE AS BLEOW

```
A.B.C.D.E
A
A.B
A-B.C
A_B-C.D.E
A.B-C.D.E
A.B.C_D-E.F
A.B.C
```

Comment: Please clarify if `A__B.C.D` should be valid or not.

Comment: A___B should be valid as it is a word character

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex for matching these combinations:

```
^\w+(?:\.\w+){0,4}(?:-\w+(?:\.\w+){0,4})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lxCFXy/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\.\w+){0,4}`: Match 0 or 4 words separated by a dot
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `-`: Match a hyphen
  - `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
  - `(?:\.\w+){0,4}`: Match 0 or 4 words separated by a dot
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes it an optional group
- `$`: End

Comment: @serah: Did this work for you?